# How can I enable notifications for upcoming scheduled maintenance events using terraform for azure postgresql flexible server using terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-postgresql

I have deployed a postgreesql server using terraform. I have configured schedule maintenance.

```
maintenance_window {
    day_of_week = 0 // Sunday
    start_hour = 21 
    start_minute = 0
  }
```

Now i want to enable notifications through mail address for upcoming scheduled maintenance events using terraform for azure postgresql flexible server..could you please  guide me how can i configure it through the terraform.is it possible to send a test event notification right after the configuration to check whether is it enabled or not ?. I really appreciate any positive reply and thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried already? Do you have any code available? If so, have you experienced any errors?

Comment: I dont have any proper code yet. @MarkoE

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to add the monitoring and email notifications for the postgresssql flexible server and got the below output***

*I have added the following script to get the email and notifications for flexible server*

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "RG_NAME"
  location = "EASTUS"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "example-vn"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "example-sn"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
  service_endpoints    = ["Microsoft.Storage"]
  delegation {
    name = "fs"
    service_delegation {
      name = "Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/flexibleServers"
      actions = [
        "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/join/action",
      ]
    }
  }
}
resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "example" {
  name                = "example.postgres.database.azure.com"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" "example" {
  name                  = "exampleVnetZone.com"
  private_dns_zone_name = azurerm_private_dns_zone.example.name
  virtual_network_id    = azurerm_virtual_network.example.id
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server" "example" {
  name                   = "example-psqlflexibleserver"
  resource_group_name    = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location               = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  version                = "12"
  delegated_subnet_id    = azurerm_subnet.example.id
  private_dns_zone_id    = azurerm_private_dns_zone.example.id
  administrator_login    = "psqladmin"
  administrator_password = "H@Sh1CoR3!"
  zone                   = "1"

  storage_mb = 32768
  backup_retention_days = 30
  geo_redundant_backup_enabled = true

  sku_name   = "GP_Standard_D4s_v3"
  depends_on = [azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link.example]
 
}


resource "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server" "examplez" {
  administrator_login    = "psqladmin"
  administrator_password = "H@Sh1CoR3!"
  name  =  "dbserverex"
  resource_group_name= "RG_NAME"
  location  =  "eastus"
  storage_mb = 32768
  backup_retention_days  =  30
  geo_redundant_backup_enabled = true
  sku_name = "GP_Standard_D4s_v3"
  
  depends_on = [azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link.example]

}

resource "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server" "dbtomonitor" {
  resource_group_name = "RG_NAME"
  name = "testdb"
  location = "eastus"
  geo_redundant_backup_enabled = true

 sku_name = "GP_Standard_D4s_v3"
   depends_on = [azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link.example]
}    
resource "azurerm_monitor_metric_alert" "example" {
  name = "example-metricalert"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.examplez.resource_group_name
  scopes = [azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.dbtomonitor.id]
  description = "action will be  triggered when cpu percent is greater than 80."
  criteria {
    metric_namespace = "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases"
    metric_name      = "cpu_percent"
    aggregation      = "Average"
    operator         = "GreaterThan"
    threshold        = 80
  }
 action {
    action_group_id = azurerm_monitor_action_group.example.id
  }
}
resource "azurerm_monitor_action_group" "example" {
  name                = "CriticalAlertsAction"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_mssql_server.example.resource_group_name
  short_name          = "p0action"

  email_receiver {
    name                    = "komaliXXXXXX@.com"
    email_address           = "youremailid"
    use_common_alert_schema = true
  }
}
```

*After adding the above script run the below steps to execute the terraform file*

```
terraform init
```

*This will initialise the file*

[image]

```
Terraform plan
```

*This will creates an execution plan and it will preview the changes that terraform plans to make the infrastructure
it will show the monitoring and email notification rules*

[image]

```
terraform apply
```

*This will creates or updates the infrastructure depending on the configuration and also creates the metric rules for the flexible server*

[image]

*For more information use this reference [link](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/monitoring_notification_channel)*

***NOTE:***
*Please make sure while writing the script, resource group , version, sku_name, admin credentials, location, storage_mb, email should be given*

Comment: is this resource azurerm_monitor_metric_alert also trigger the upcoming scheduled maintenance alert or do i have to create specific resource for exampl e "azurerm_monitor_scheduled_query_rules_alert" "schedule_maintenance_alert"

Comment: @eku thanks for the reply, ```resource azurerm_monitor_metric_alert``` it will not trigger the upcoming schedule maintenance, we have to create the specific resource like ```azurerm_monitor_scheduled_query_rules_alert```.

Comment: where, can i share my schedule maintenance code? in the comment i cant :(